# How low is the visibility of the model for the user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to make sure that only the creator of the model could see it, but other participants could not see it, that is, the person who created the model could only see it from his account, and from another account the person saw only his own

I have a models.py model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

views.py

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = 'products_list.html'


class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product

class NewProductView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    template_name = 'product_form.html'
    model = Product
    form_class = NewProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_list_page')

class EditProductView(LoginRequiredMixin ,UpdateView):
    template_name = 'product_form.html'
    model = Product
    form_class = EditProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_list_page')
```

how to make it visible only to the current who created it, so that another user sees only his own model that he created. How do I limit the visibility of a model to its creator only?

Answer (score 0):

First into your Product model you should include a foreign key to the user, that's better than just saving the username.

Product Model:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then on your list view you can filter with:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).all()
```